# Joining a specific GKTurnBasedMatch based upon its ID

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center, gamekit

I'd like to allow players of my game to join a specific match. For example, **PlayerA** starts a `GKTurnBasedMatch` via `findMatchForRequest`. He then wants his friend to join, but rather than hoping that his friend searches for him on game center, **PlayerA** wants to send the `matchID` to **PlayerB** (say, via social media, or whatever... my goal is actually to let players use a custom-URL schema to send game links to friends, eg, `mygame://join/**matchID**`).

From here, **PlayerB** can obviously load the match with `GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchWithID`... but how can he explicitly request to join it?

```
[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchWithID:matchID withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error) {
    if(error || !match) {
      [[AMAlertManager sharedManager] showError:i18n(@"errors.invalidInvite")];
    }
    else {
       // Now what?
    }
  }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring this out, and it's pretty simple. The trick is that once you load the GKTurnBasedMatch you just want to take a look at the found match's participants (these are the players already in the game), and then create an array of player IDs from them. You can use this array as the `.playersToInvite` property when doing a `findMatchForRequest`.

In fact, you could just pass off this array to the `handleInviteFromGameCenter` delegate method, to reuse existing code for game center invites.

This function will let a player join a specific `matchID`:

```
- (void)handleInviteToMatchID:(NSString*)matchID {
  [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchWithID:matchID withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error) {
    if(error || !match) {
      [[AMAlertManager sharedManager] showError:i18n(@"errors.invite.invalid")];
    }
    else if(match.status != GKTurnBasedMatchStatusMatching) {
      [[AMAlertManager sharedManager] showError:i18n(@"errors.invite.notMatching")];
    }
    else {
      NSMutableArray *playersToInvite = [NSMutableArray array];
      for(GKTurnBasedParticipant *player in match.participants) {
        if(player.playerID) {
          [playersToInvite addObject:player.playerID];
        }
      }
      [self handleInviteFromGameCenter:playersToInvite];
    }
  }];
}
```

Comment: There's a small bug you may be overlooking.  If a group of players have multiple games going at once, there may be several games with the same group of participants.  In that case, if you only include actual participants, you may get the right group, but the wrong match, returning a different matchID than expected.